# R data frame subsetting concepts

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame called data.  I have a column called ColB with all NA values and a column called ColC with all integer values and no NAs.

When I use the subset syntax I get some false results (all NAs):

```
nrow(data[data$ColB == "XXXX",])
```

But when I run the same syntax using the which function I get no results, as I would expect and want.

```
data[which(data$ColB== "XXXX"),]
```

Also, when I run the following:

```
{data[data$ColC == 185,]}
```

I get the correct result/output which is one matching row.

Why is this?  Is this something about having NA in the data? And is subsetting by column reference (instead of using subset function) without using which not recommended?

Answer (score 1):

`NA` is *a logical constant of length 1 which contains a missing value indicator.*

And e.g. `which( c( NA,NA,NA) )` returns a zero length integer vector as none of the comparisons can be considered `TRUE`, the same as if you tried `which( c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE) )`. Therefore you are trying to subset your data.frame with nothing, returning nothing.

If you need to do comparisons using data with `NA` values, use the `is.na()`, function, e.g. consider:

```
x <- c( NA , is.na(NA) , NA )
which( x )
#[1] 2
```